# Could use some help implementing Perlin noise to generate terrain in my game engine.

Tags: c++, perlin-noise

so i am working on building a game engine by following some YouTube tutorials. I am coding in C++ and using the SDL2 and SDL2 Texture libraries for the functionality. To generate the noise I am using A header and .cpp called Fast Noise acquired from GitHub. The .cpp i use to draw the map is below

```
#include "Map.h"
#include "TextureManager.h"
#include "FastNoise.h"


int lvl1[20][25] = {




{ 0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
{ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
};

Map::Map() 
{
dirt = TextureManager::LoadTexture("Assets/TileSets/Dirt.png");
grass = TextureManager::LoadTexture("Assets/TileSets/Grass.png");
water = TextureManager::LoadTexture("Assets/TileSets/Water.png");


LoadMap(lvl1);

src.x = src.y = 0;
src.w = dest.w = 32;
src.h = dest.h = 32;

dest.x = dest.y = 0;
}

void Map::LoadMap(int arr[20][25])
{
for (int row = 0; row < 20; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < 25; column++)
    {
        map[row][column] = arr[row][column];
    }
}


}

void Map::DrawMap()
{
int type = 0;

for (int row = 0; row < 20; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < 25; column++)
    {
        type = map[row][column];

        dest.x = column * 32;
        dest.y = row * 32;

        switch (type) 
        {
        case 0:
            TextureManager::Draw(water, src, dest);
            break;
        case 1:
            TextureManager::Draw(grass, src, dest);
            break;
        case 2:
            TextureManager::Draw(dirt, src, dest);


        default:
            break;
        }

    }
 }
}
```

The code to  create a noise is

```
FastNoise myNoise; // Create a FastNoise object
myNoise.SetNoiseType(FastNoise::SimplexFractal); // Set the desired noise 
type

float heightMap[32][32]; // 2D heightmap to create terrain

for (int x = 0; x < 32; x++)
{
for (int y = 0; y < 32; y++)
{
    heightMap[x][y] = myNoise.GetNoise(x,y);
}
}
```

What i am struggling with is how to implement it so that instead of using the lvl1 int array it stores and uses the values created by the noise to draw the terrain. If it is not apparent by the post i am fairly new to programming, the game engine i am creating is fairly functional, but i want to create procedural generated terrain, instead of hand making it.

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? How to replace `lvl1` data with `heightMap` data?

Comment: Yes I have tried several approaches but have failed to do so. I want to use height map data to assign tiles on the map.